# Rack Middleware For Monitoring 7 Days Traffic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I need some help in understanding how to start with this project.
I have to write a rack middleware for monitoring 7days traffic and the accordingly if the traffic increases beyond the threshold then block the particular I.P generating the traffic.

Basic I want to prevent my site from DDOS Attack, and I want to write my custom RACK app.

It does not matter how amateur the app is, but I need to understand how it all works, that is why I want to make this app.

Can someone please guide me in this.

Some resources that I have seen already are Rack Throttle and Rack Defense gem,But i am still confused,Please guide me in solving this.

Comment: You mention two gems that do something like what you want, but do not say why they do not meet your needs. What do you want to do that they cannot?

Comment: so ya you are right,most of the functionality is given to me by those gems, but I am having a tough time understanding them and then builidng some additional logic on top of it.So basically I need to know how can I monitor 7 days traffic and then from the next week onwards keep comparing the data and if the traffic on any particular day or week is more than 50%, then either block the ip generating those requests or redirect them to a captcha.I am confused how will I implement this on top of these gems

Comment: This seems like quite a specific requirement. Is there a particular business need for it? Many people have the same problem as you and are happy with the solution as provided by these gems, so what makes your case different? Maybe you will be OK with the same solution as them.

Comment: By same solution do you mean that these gems have the inbuilt functionality of tracking 7 days traffic, if so then can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: See my answer, it would be easy to implement by inheriting from `RackThrottle::TimeWindow`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this is only for learning purpose so here is small breakdown of how this could get implemented. For using this in production I definitely recommend to just use Rack Throttle as there are many corner cases and options which we don't cover in this simple example.

This is the smallest possible Rack middleware which just prints out the IP

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env rackup

require "rack"

class Limiter
  attr_reader :app

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    puts request.ip
    app.call(env)
  end
end

use Limiter

run lambda { |env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ["Hello, world!\n"]] }
```

A middleware must be classes as they need to have an initializer which will be passed the next app in the chain. The call method gets the request environment, does whatever it needs to do and then calls the next app. Our middleware just prints out the IP address for now.

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L354
https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/rack

Now we can store the request count for each ip address and block the request if it exceeds a limit:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env rackup

require "rack"

class Limiter
  attr_reader :app, :options, :counter

  def initialize(app, options)
    @app = app
    @options = options
    @counter = {}
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)

    if counter[request.ip].to_i > options[:max].to_i
      [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ["You are blocked, request count: #{counter[request.ip]}\n"]]
    else
      counter[request.ip] ||= 0
      counter[request.ip] += 1
      app.call(env)
    end
  end
end

use Limiter, max: 1

run lambda { |env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ["Hello, world!\n"]] }
```

If you execute this app it will block you after the first request.

You can see that we now initialize the middleware with an option `max: 1` which we can access inside our middleware from the `options`. We use it to determine when to block a request.

We also initialize a simple hash in which we store the request count per IP address. Please note that this only works if you have a single web server. If you have more servers you need to sync the count between the servers. Good options are Redis or Memcache.

In general, the Rack Throttle code is quite readable so I recommend to read through it. Most of the logic is implemented in the [Limiter class](https://github.com/dryruby/rack-throttle/blob/master/lib/rack/throttle/limiter.rb#L35) from which most other classes inherit.

### Edit

The question author asked this

> By same solution do you mean that these gems have the inbuilt functionality of tracking 7 days traffic, if so then can you explain me how to do that?

AFAIK Rack::Throttle does not implement this functionality yet but it would be easy to add by inheriting from `TimeWindow`

```rb
  class Weekly < RackThrottle::TimeWindow
    ##
    # @param  [#call]                  app
    # @param  [Hash{Symbol => Object}] options
    # @option options [Integer] :max   (3600)
    def initialize(app, options = {})
      super
    end

    ##
    def max_per_week(request = nil)
      @max_per_week ||= options[:max_per_week] || options[:max] || 3_600 * 7
    end

    alias_method :max_per_window, :max_per_week

    protected

    ##
    # @param  [Rack::Request] request
    # @return [String]
    def cache_key(request)
      # %U returns the calendar week
      [super, Time.now.strftime('%U')].join(':')
    end
  end
```

Please note this will track by calendar week. If you want to have a rolling tracker you need to count daily and then fetch the last 7 days.